# MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-1.4

I have the problem defaultStringLength() despite several seeks. I explain you  my procedure.

In the file folder database -> 2018_10_24_103651_create_devis_table.php I have that:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDevisTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('start_adress');
            $table->string('end_adress');
            $table->text('remarks');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('devis');
    }
}
```

Then, I must to change the file AppServiceProvider.php

Here is my modification

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(255);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

After, I run the command next `php artisan migrate`and I have like result the error message -> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()

Do you have an idea please ? 
I thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: `Schema::defaultStringLength(191); `used @anais_stem

Comment: Jignesh Joisar: even problem I don't understand why it' doesn't works ???

Comment: what version of laravel you are using

Comment: @anais_stem read this article https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: @ Shaielndra Gupta : I have the version 5.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defaultStringLength this is introduced in Laravel 5.4

You can update the Laravel version

or

You specify the length as `$table->string('coumname', 255);` You cannot specify more than `255`

Comment: I am trying your second solution but it's doesn't works:                                     
 public function up(){
        Schema::create('biodatas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('test');
            $table->string('coumname', 255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: are you still getting error if yes the tell me what erroe you are gatting

Comment: @ Shaielndra Gupta : ohhh it's works sorry !!!! Thaaaannnnkkkkk youuuuuu !!! I erased Schema::defaultStringLength(255); on the file AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: @ Shaielndra Gupta : I think to update my version also

Comment: yes you can new versions of laravel have new fetures and dont forget to upvote also