# Php artisan migrate gives different result with the same code

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-9

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzROi.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ztC.png)

Pic 2 is the usual laravel migration tables that i created. Pic 1 is the laravel migration tables that i newly created. They have the same code with same foreign key only with different attributes name. Why is pic 1 only have varchar(191) instead of varchar(255), and the foreign key doesnt apply from migrations anymore? Before pic 1, i did ran some stuff on terminal for deployment purpose like npm build. Is the terminal the cause of this?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('calibrations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Identification_No');
            $table->foreign('Identification_No')->references('Identification_No')->on('fieldequips');
            $table->string('Calibration_point');
            $table->date('Expired_Date');
            $table->date('Calibration_Date');
            $table->date('Next_Due_Date');
            $table->string('Correction_factor');
            $table->string('Validated_by');
            $table->date('Validated_Date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('calibrations');
    }
};
```

Comment: Where is the database migration source code you're referring to?

Comment: I added the code, but i dont think its the code problem because it works perfectly fine days ago

Comment: [MySqlBuilder::defaultStringLength()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967229/mysqlbuilderdefaultstringlength)

Comment: [Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#index-lengths-mysql-mariadb)

Comment: That was what caused the string length to be 191. But i had the confusion of whats leads to it becoming 191, I never edited the app service provider file before.

Comment: Also the foreign key is still not assigned, what could be the problem?

Comment: Where is the migration of the `fieldequips` database table?

Comment: In addition, what Laravel framework version are you using?

Comment: ```fieldequips``` is another table. Im trying to set up a foreign key in ```calibrations``` that link to ```fieldequips```

Comment: Im using laravel 9.31.0 . Its really weird because i encounter this problem where certain code are still working but when i copy-paste it, it doesn't work anymore. Before this, i met a lot of problem deploying my project to domains so i ran a lot of command via the terminal. I wonder if thats the problem.

Comment: I'm already aware that it belongs to another table. Could you kindly share it as well?

Answer (score 0):

In **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** you should change `Schema::defaultStringLength(191)` to `Schema::defaultStringLength(255)`, I guess